# IMG tag not displaying after PHP echo statement

Tags: php, html, image

I've looked at other questions but haven't found the answer, I'm echoing an image from a DB query - which works - into an image tag, but the image isnt displaying in the browser, however the code is all in the source and when I open the image in my browser it is there!

my code;

```
echo '<a href="http://www.example.com/adClick.php?id='.$a[0]['id'].'" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.example.com/images/ads/JobAlert/'.$a[0]['Image'].'" /></a>';
```

rendered html;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<p></p><a href="http://www.example.com/adClick.php?id=3" target="_blank">
                        <img src="http://www.example.com/images/ads/JobAlert/eb6daad2c02b3ba3310c03b3ef77e0ceb801cd8b74742356b2e7af37ef39a5b468752706.png" />
                        </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you echoing it before page load or after page has loaded? does the `<a>` element render well?

Comment: Updated the question, also as I have said, the echoed image is correct (so is the id)

Comment: And the <a>/<img> is not hidden / rendered somewhere else by CSS rules?

Comment: @RMK nope that is the whole html

Comment: ...and does it work when you hard-code the `<img>`? We have no way to tell if the image source is even correct.

Comment: First step in troubleshooting (for me) is "naming convention". Now it may be a silly question, but have you checked to see if it's actually called `Image`, and not `image`? I.e. `['Image']` or `['image']` I had to ask, it happens. Linux and Windows servers act differently to naming conventions.

Comment: @Fred the naming is correct (checked twice)

Comment: @WesleyMurch As i said, I've clicked the link in the source code to the image and it works

Comment: can you link is to your site?

Comment: @simonfuniic Ok. From what I can tell by the generated image name, its length is long, **73 characters** actually, minus the file extension. Could it be that your string is too long and/or your DB is set to a fixed size/length? Could be the hashing is too long. Check your DB table.

Comment: @simonfuniic All I can suggest is that you post a demo with the actual code linking to your site.

Comment: @WesleyMurch what do you mean? one is to the the image the other is where the user should be taken

Comment: @simonfuniic Ignore my deleted comment.

Comment: @Fred that can't be it as the link in the source code to the image works perfectly (generated by the PHP)

Comment: @simonfuniic Ok, we've eliminated that. Next question, which actually should have been the first. Are you running this via the Web or `localhost`?

Comment: @Localhost Through my webserver

Comment: @simonfuniic Sounds like `local` (to you) issue then, and I am not familiar with `localhost`. Sorry, I can't be of further help.

Comment: Prompted on by @Leonard Pauli I tried Google chrome instead of FireFox and the image displays, three times.

Comment: @what do you mean with three times?

Comment: sorry that was my mistake, just once - the image is displayed in chrome, once, as expected

Comment: @Sergio I've shortened the file name to about 8 chars and still no luck (in Firefox)

Comment: Share a live link, people are engaged now, soon they will go away to other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try empty the cache and check the address once more. We have had a problem where we saved a psd as png (but the content was still a psd), so it didn't show up in the img element, but when we followed the image link in the inspector, it was there...

Some browsers lowercase the url. Try to replace JobAlert with jobalert and it won't work in any browser, probably because you have missed [NC] (Non Case sensitive) in .htaccess. Make sure the lowercase url will work, then the image should work too!

Edit: Simon later pointed out that the image for some reason was blocked by the browser plugin AdBlock, something to keep in mind if your working with ads. Remember that you could ask to whitelist your site https://adblockplus.org/en/acceptable-ads.

Good luck with finding the problem!

Comment: Tried, didn't work, I just tried again and still nothing, thanks anyway

Comment: No problem :) What about restarting the browser or randomly clicking everywhere? =)

Comment: Oh, and you don't need that long names, do you? (A-z0-9)^72 is... a lot. Really.

Comment: I'll try restart my browser, also I'll cut down my file name and see if that helps

Comment: Prompted on by @Leonard Pauli I tried Google chrome instead of FireFox and the image displays, three times.

Comment: @Lenoard Pauli I've shortened the file name to about 8 chars and still no luck (in Firefox)

Comment: Hmp.. I think that's a problem.. Do you mind posting the real link to the real image, or just upload a new dummy image if that one is private?

Comment: I FOUND IT!!! Goto http://www.mypromowork.com/images/ads/JobAlert/eb6daad2c02b3bf.png and then http://www.mypromowork.com/images/ads/jobalert/eb6daad2c02b3bf.png

Comment: WOOOOOOOW what?! How?!

Comment: oooooooh isee! the captials!

Comment: Wait where in my code do I mess this up?

Comment: Probably in .htaccess, see my edited answer :)

Comment: Please also include in your answer that AdBlock can also do this (just found out this was my problem!!!! - the stupidest mistake ever), thanks.

Comment: @simonfuniic I guess I was partially right; about the "naming convention", where letter case matters. I'm glad you found a solution to your problem.

Comment: Glad you found it! Check out my edit :)

Comment: In my case, the ADBlock was the problem, i saw this after much hours working, when  read your response, thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Do the images reside on your server? 
If not maybe the server is blocking the deep linking of images.
If the image is on your server - did you test it by copying the exact link generated (copy / paste from the html)?

Comment: The images are stored on my server, and I have tried the exactlink in the source code